# Create query where results don't contain the keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when I want to select all data in MySQL database, so I want to select all words except `apple` in one column.

Table name: tb_fruits:

```
+========+
|  word  |
+========+
| apple  |
+--------+
| banana |
+--------+
| mango  |
+--------+
```

So I want to fetch all the data in fruits table without data `apple`.

`"Select * from tb_fruits ...."`

Comment: i think your asking for: `WHERE Fruits not like '%apple%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_fruits
WHERE word <> 'apple'
```

Please reference documentation and some basic tutorials for help with this.

[Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

[NOT LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like)

[NOT EQUAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Comment: @Duwiirwanto you’re welcome. Best of luck to you in your learning.